# SQL Server: Backup location

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

I am working on a SQL Server database and ran the following command to figure out where the database is backing up to:

```
SELECT TOP 1 M.physical_device_name
FROM msdb..backupset S
JOIN msdb..backupmediafamily M ON M.media_set_id=S.media_set_id
WHERE S.database_name = 'MyDB'
```

The physical_device_name says: **HTSQLServerMyDB**

I don't see any maintenance plans or jobs that I can figure out that do this backup. I am trying to figure out where it is doing this backup. If I go into **Server Objects** then **Backup Devices** it is empty.
How can I determine where are my backups?

I am running SQL Server 2016 (13.0.4001.0).

Comment: could be an Agent Job, a Maintenance Plan, a Powershell Script ... lots of different ways you could run a script to do this

Comment: There's only one maintenance plan and it is disabled, I looked through all the jobs and none are backup. I just want to know what is `HTSQLServerMyDB` since supposedly that is where it is doing the backup.

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you have anything in `sys.backup_devices`?

Comment: Also, what is shown for  ```M.device_type ``` if you add that into your query?

Comment: The Device Type is indeed 7 (Virtual Device). The sys.backup_devices table is empty. his server is hosted on a third party hosting service. I believe they use VMWare. Does this mean that it is part of their VM Backup?

Comment: Probably yes - it's VM backup.